# Google Drive API (java) - OAuth2 Get Request for mp4 Video Stream - HTML5 Video causes Status 403 (Forbidden)

Tags: google-drive-api, video-streaming, html5-video, google-docs

Via localhost

1. I'm successfully accessing https://docs.google.com/get_video_info?docid=[google drive file id] via a com.google.api.services.drive.Drive and receiving the intended response content.
2. I decode the content using URLDecoder.decode, using the content charset defined in the response to retrieve the first video/mp4 url in the url_encoded_fmt_stream_map section.
3. I then use the said url in an HTML page for a html5 video src.  The video plays without any issues.

Via AWS instance (centos, apache tomcat 7, java 8, ssl cert SHA-256, character-encoding: UTF-8, service timezone: America/New_York)

Steps 1 & 2 work exactly the same...

3. When using the url in the html5 video src attribute the browser receives a status 403 (forbidden) w/o any response content.

Any ideas?  If I can provide additional information please let me know.  Thank you in advance for anyone that can assist.

Comment: try appending "?access_token={access_token}" to url

Comment: I think I've determined the problem...  When I retrieve the stream information from the https://docs.google.com/get_video_info on the server-side, google is noting my ip address.  When I use the url locally I'm using the same ip address as my server.  However, in production my browser and server have different ip address, which causes the 403.  Checked the https://docs.google.com/get_video_info and it does not accept cross domain, which would have allow us to retrieve the information via the browser...  There is not solution for the given "equation" unless one of the parameters changes :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Drive File's downloadUrl + "?access_token=[access token]" for the video source works and is relatively secure since the access token expires in approx. 1000 secs.  Only limitation, I'm aware of, is a download limit google drive imposes, but does not document.  Asked customer support, who is very helpful, but they could not give me an actual # of downloads.  The work around for the download limit is duplicating the video, waiting for the video to propagate and then deleting this original.

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem with that links too:
https://r10---sn-4wg7en7l.c.docs.google.com/videoplayback?requiressl=yes&id=74dd098b62525d54&itag=43&source=webdrive&app=docs&ip=80.184.78.34&ipbits=8&expire=1442347753&sparams=requiressl,id,itag,source,ip,ipbits,expire&signature=354E8C0EB3F39BB4C5AD6B1CE11DC14C2156022A.88E599E991106B4CF9CE94B47E86EF57348C2F46&key=ck2&mm=30&mn=sn-4wg7en7l&ms=nxu&mt=1442344063&mv=m&pl=23&type=video/webm&quality=medium&timestamp=1442344153994&length_seconds=1441
looks like they became IP tied.
But these guys get redirector links somehow:
http://kissanime.com/Anime/God-Eater/Episode-007?id=116511

Comment: I've also noticed that I'm able to copy the entire video tag from localhost, which plays, into my public site and the video plays without a problem...  I was not able to gain anything from redirector.google.com.  There has to bee something we're missing

Comment: how do you get  redirector.google.com links? (do you?)
is there any onpion to get google drive atom feed? like picasa:
http://picasaweb.google.com/data/entry/api/user/118006485718804560084/albumid/6175556146550960673/photoid/6177447016829862098 - it contains redirector links

Comment: I'm not familiar with the redirector url, but I'm guessing it has something to do with retired Google Video, based on it's name.  However, the redirector service seems to be pointing to the same google cdn...  still doesn't shed any light on my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Interested in a long term solution to this issue too...

Cytu.be came up with a workaround, but it is far from ideal.

https://github.com/calzoneman/sync/commits/gdrive-youtube-hack